# How do I create a Flux using generate wrapping calls that return a Mono

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, project-reactor, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an example where I want to use Flux.generate because I don't want to make the expensive blocking call unless / until a subscriber is asking for it. Specifically, I am calling Elasticsearch multiple times (effectively doing paging) until there are no more hits. I have implemented this using standard blocking calls in a `Iterator<SearchResponse>`. Where each call to the generate lambda blocks and the flux is then finished with `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`. However, I would like to use Spring's `ReactiveElasticsearchClient` that returns a `Mono<SearchResponse>` but still want to do it one at a time.

Here is the previous code using blocking:

```
  public Iterator<SearchResponse> createDeepQueryIterator(@NonNull PITSearchInput input){
    return new PointInTimeIterator(elasticClient, input);
  }

  public Flux<SearchResponse> createDeepQueryFlux(@NonNull PITSearchInput input){
    return Flux.<SearchResponse, PointInTimeIterator>generate(
            () -> new PointInTimeIterator(elasticClient, input),
            (deepQueryIterator, sink) -> {
              if (deepQueryIterator.hasNext()) {
                sink.next(deepQueryIterator.next());
              }else{
                sink.complete();
              }
              return deepQueryIterator;
            },
            (deepQueryIterator) -> deepQueryIterator.shutdown())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
  }
```

The above works well in that it waits to make the next call to ES until a (the) subscriber is ready for the next block of data.

In the below I am trying to use Spring's `ReactiveElasticsearchClient` but the issue is that multiple calls are make to ES before subscriber has processed the first.

```
  public Flux<SearchResponse> createDeepQuery(PointInTimeIteratorFactory.PITSearchInput input) {
    log.info("Creating flux");

    AtomicReference<PitId> pitId = new AtomicReference<>();
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    Mono<PitId> pitIdMono =
        Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> {
              pitId.set(createPIT(input));
              return pitId.get();
            })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    Mono<SearchResponse> searchResponseMono =
        pitIdMono.flatMap(
            p -> {
              log.info("Calling search");
              return reactiveElasticsearchClient.searchForResponse(createSearchRequestFrom(p, input));
            });
    Flux<SearchResponse> expand =
        searchResponseMono
            .expand(
                (searchResponse -> {
                  int hitCount = searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length;
                  count.addAndGet(hitCount);
                  log.info("Previous returned {} hits totaling {}", hitCount, count.get());

                  if (count.get() > input.getMaxTotalSize()
                  || hitCount < input.getMaxSizePerQuery()){
                    log.info("Returning empty");
                    return Mono.empty();
                  }

                  log.info("Calling search");
                  pitId.set(new PitId(searchResponse.pointInTimeId()));
                  return reactiveElasticsearchClient.searchForResponse(
                      createSearchRequestFrom(searchResponse, input));
                }))
            .doFinally(
                p -> {
                  deletePIT(pitId.get());
                });
    return expand;
  }
```

So the question is not to use the reactive client's ability to return a `Mono<SearchResponse>` in a `Flux` but only doing so one-at-a-time as needed by the subscriber.

The below is the logging from the Flux -> Mono method above with the `PitTest` logging coming from the test onNext() of the flux.

```
2021-12-02 13:13:37.300  INFO 13704 --- [           main] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Creating flux
2021-12-02 13:13:37.346  INFO 13704 --- [oundedElastic-1] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Creating PIT
2021-12-02 13:13:37.407  INFO 13704 --- [oundedElastic-1] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Calling search
2021-12-02 13:13:38.176  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Previous returned 50 hits totaling 50
2021-12-02 13:13:38.177  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Calling search
2021-12-02 13:13:38.177  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Setting searchAfter to 1634877306267
2021-12-02 13:13:38.228  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Previous returned 50 hits totaling 100
2021-12-02 13:13:38.228  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Calling search
2021-12-02 13:13:38.228  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Setting searchAfter to 1634877606162
2021-12-02 13:13:38.271  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Previous returned 50 hits totaling 150
2021-12-02 13:13:38.271  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Calling search
2021-12-02 13:13:38.272  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Setting searchAfter to 1634877606362
2021-12-02 13:13:38.311  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Previous returned 50 hits totaling 200
2021-12-02 13:13:38.312  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Calling search
2021-12-02 13:13:38.312  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Setting searchAfter to 1634877906244
2021-12-02 13:13:38.344  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Previous returned 50 hits totaling 250
2021-12-02 13:13:38.345  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Returning empty
2021-12-02 13:13:38.345  INFO 13704 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.a.t.ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory : Closing PIT ReactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory.PitId(id=m_2xAwENYWN0aXZpdHlzdG9yZRZQQkRGWldmclI2cWZITEpoWDI1cGlRABZCZU8xbm55ZlFabXREYmNEdThESG1RAAAAAAAAWQcTFm5BcXdPU2xTUWE2bEU4dkVPVkpkWFEBFlBCREZaV2ZyUjZxZkhMSmhYMjVwaVEAAA==)
2021-12-02 13:13:40.171  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-1] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : [1634877306066]
2021-12-02 13:13:42.172  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-2] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : [1634877306272]
2021-12-02 13:13:44.172  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-3] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : [1634877606166]
2021-12-02 13:13:46.173  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-4] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : [1634877906057]
2021-12-02 13:13:48.174  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-1] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : [1634877906248]
2021-12-02 13:13:48.174  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-1] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : Complete
2021-12-02 13:13:48.174  INFO 13704 --- [           main] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : blah
2021-12-02 13:13:48.175  INFO 13704 --- [     parallel-1] p.actss.activity.store.PitTest           : onComplete
```

Update: Adding the PitTest code for completeness:

```
  @Test
  void testReactoiveFluxIt() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<SearchResponse> deepQuery = reactivePointInTimeIteratorFactory.createDeepQuery(...);

    deepQuery
        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
        .doOnNext(p -> log.info(Arrays.toString(p.getHits().getHits()[0].getSortValues()))) //
        .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("Complete")) //
        .doFinally(p -> log.info(p.toString()))
        .blockLast();
    log.info("blah");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
```

Comment: Subscriber should be able to control the flow and request items one by one. Sample code that shows what your subscriber doing would help.

Comment: Issue in this case is that multiple calls were made to elsticsearch before the subscriber code was given the first. Currently all the subscriber code does is print the "sort" of the last hit in an onNext(). See the lines logged by PitTest. But notice that "Calling search" was executed multiple times before the first PitTest logging. @lkatiforis

Comment: Why does `PitTest` run on the parallel scheduler?

Comment: @lkatiforis The original Mono starts with a fromCallable and has an onSubscribe(boundedElastic).
```Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> {
              pitId.set(createPIT(input));
              return pitId.get();
            })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());```

Comment: Event without the `subscribeOn` I still see all the searches happening before PitTest gets the first

Comment: `delayElements` switches to parallel scheduler and delay each emitted element by 2 seconds. This is why sort values are printed afterward.

Comment: @lkatiforis That was it. Thanks! Since I was on the wrong track, I can delete the question or if you want to post the answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delayElements` switches to parallel scheduler and delays each emitted element by 2 seconds. This is why sort values are printed afterward.